# Configuring RAID on Intel DX58SO CTRL+I does not enter RAID Config Utility

Tags: hard-drive, boot, raid, sata, intel-rst

I have two 3TB HDD plugged into SATA 0 and SATA 1. I configured the drives for RAID in the BIOS and now when I boot I see the RAID config screen. The screen lists all my drives as it should and says **press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to enter the configuration utility**.

I spent all day yesterday swapping USB ports and keyboards with no change. No matter how many times I hit that combo it never enters the utility and continues to boot.

Any ideas as to why it is not entering the RAIS configuration utility?

This video shows the same utility: [**Intel RAID Setup Guide**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbCigLJO7Q4#t=121)

Comment: I take it you have already tried spamming ctrl-i, even before it prompts you to press it? ...

Comment: Also, ctrl-i also may close the config utility without warning, so spamming it may also be your problem ... Try maybe tap it once at the right time

Comment: You may want to try resetting your BIOS. You may have changed many different ports and different keyboard - your BIOS may have simply stopped recognising USB devices such as keyboards... a reset may resolve this...

Answer (score 1):

**Enable USB Legacy** option in the BIOS to fix it.

<kbd>F2</kbd> >
CONFIGURATION >
ON-BOARD DEVICES >
USB CONFIGURATION >
USB Legacy

<kbd>F10</kbd> (save and exit).

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.

Notice that without this configuration you do not have the keyboard ready when the message is displayed. You can test it by hitting <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and see that nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

[Update your BIOS](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=23056&lang=eng&ProdId=3018).

Intel has been providing regular BIOS updates for your motherboard for the last 5 years.  They document a [long list of fixes](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/23056/eng/SO_5600_ReleaseNotes.pdf) including ones related to RAID and USB.

If you're still having problems after updating, try disabling `Fast Boot` in the BIOS.